# Inheritance with 3 classes

Tags: java, inheritance

Code:

```
    class Super {
      void print(Super a) {
         System.out.print("Super");
      }
    }
    class Base extends Super{
      void print(Base a) {
         System.out.print("Base");
      }
    }
    class Derived extends Base{
      void print(Derived a) {
         System.out.print("Derived");
      }
    }
    class Test {
      public static void main(String args[]){
        Super a1= new Super();
        Super b1= new Base();
        Base c1= new Derived();
        a1.print(new Base());
        b1.print(new Derived());
        c1.print(new Derived());
      }
    }
```

**output: "SuperSuperBase"**

How does it work, explain please? I understand that it is impossible to give short answer, but.. it's so hard for understanding

Comment: Well, which of those results do you not understand? What would you expect it to print, and why?

Comment: There is no method overriding  in your code, the three methods have different signatures.

Comment: Note that `print()` methods do not care about the parameter.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yeah, inheritance, my bad.

Comment: I thought there is overriding. I didn't see one moment- that there is the overloading of methods because of "The parameter types are different". Thank you for helping

Comment: c1 is Derived instance. And have method c1.print(Derived a). When we use c1.print(new Derived()) types of parameter are similar. Why in runtime less useful method Base.print(Base a) was used?

Answer (score 1):

> output: "SuperSuperBase"

```
    Super a1= new Super();
    a1.print(new Base());
```

`Super` class object is created w.r.t `Super`. `print()` method of `Super` class will be invoked.

```
    Super b1= new Base();
    b1.print(new Derived());
```

Here `b1` is reference of type `Super` class. So `print()` method of `Super` class will be invoked.

```
    Base c1= new Derived();      
    c1.print(new Derived());
```

Here `c1` is reference of type `Base` class. So `print()` method of `Base` class will be invoked.

Comment: But `b1` is actually Base instance, not Super.

Comment: @m0skit0 there is no polymorphism going on here, since the print() method is not overridden. It's overloaded, which is very different.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, you're right, my bad, I removed that.

Comment: @JBNizet   c1 is Derived instance. And have method c1.print(Derived a). When we use c1.print(new Derived()) types of parameter are similar. Why in runtime  less useful method Base.print(Base a) was used?

Comment: @E.Simchuk Because polymorphism doesn't depend on the types of parameters. It depends on the type of the object on which you call the method. All the compiler knows about c1 is that it's a reference to a Base. So it looks for a method print() accepting a Derived as parameter in Base, and in its superclass Super. It finds two, but Base.print() is the most specific one of the two. So it picks that one. And since Derived.print() does NOT override Base.print() (because the type of the parameter is not the same), the Base.print() method is executed at runtime.

Comment: @JBNizet  Thank you, it is more clear now. Need to feel that structure=)